# Нагрузочное тестирование REST API nodejs

Tags: node.js

Нужно провести нагрузочное тестирование для nodejs по разным роутам REST API. Поисковик дал кучу информации, но хотелось бы услышать ответ от людей имевших опыт с такой задачей, что использовать для теста нагрузки что-бы можно было определять среднее время ответа сервера и при N запросов в единицу времени например.

Comment: [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) попробуйте

Comment: apache benchmarks, jmeter, yandex.tank, gatling